# How do I update a field in DynamoDB?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I would like to update a field in my DynamoDB table called 'AppTable' using the  AWS-Amplify methods that were generated when creating the corresponding CRUD cloud-api (e.g. PUT, GET, POST, DELETE).

```
The API methods reside in awsmobilejs/backend/cloud-api/AppTable/app.js
```

I can simply use API.put to add to this table. e.g:

```
apiResponse = API.put('AppTableCRUD', path, body)

body: {
    "uploaderBool": true,
    "userId": 'user1',
    "itemId": '10005',
    "Username": "first_app_user",
    "Email": "user@myapp.com",
    "NumberList": 
       [
        "7.9",
        "5.7",
        "3.4",
        "4.9"
       ],
    "AverageNumber":[
        "5.5"
       ],
     }
    }
```

What i want to do, is update the NumberList field with a function in my react-native app, count how many numbers in the list on DynamoDB, then calculate/write an updated number called AverageNumber.

If i use a current API.put method i have to put in this ENTIRE body everytime (this list could be hundreds of thousand of entries so Get, then Put with a single update is absurd).

How do i just append a single number to the NumberList and update the AverageNumber fields?

Comment: DynamoDB itself supports the [UpdateItem operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html). If that's not exposed by Amplify, you're probably out of luck here.